# The iTunes 10 notification icon looks like crap in Windows 7, is there any way to change it?

Tags: windows-7, icons, itunes-10

[image]

Comment: Apple would answer: get a Mac. They don't really care how well (or not!) it works on Windows...

Comment: @torbengb I'm pretty sure they *do* care whether or not it works in Windows. That is, unless they want to miss 90% of the market (and no, I'm absolutely not a Windows fanboy but just saying).

Comment: @Nimmy Yes *it works* but not *well*.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can change it with [xn Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm) or [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/). File-> open iTunes.exe (from your program files directory) using Resource Hacker. In the icon folder in resource hacker, right click the icon file and select "replace resource". Then choose a ico file to replace the icon. I was able to do it by changing the icon in folder 16 or Icon group 153. Not sure if you need to change any others. Icons might vary based on screen resolution and colors.

After you changed the icon, do a "file->save as" and save it as iTunes.exe to your desktop or something. Then swap out your new iTunes.exe executible with the one in program files.

Comment: Just as an additional resource, you can get some very high-res icons on [IconArchive](http://www.iconarchive.com/) and you might want to check out their [alternative iTunes icons](http://www.iconarchive.com/category/media/itunes-10-icons-by-pixelresort.html) section.